# Find the permutations that sums to the three smallest numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

I asked the same thing yesterday but was finding a hard time finding the right sentence to describe my problem, so I deleted it. But here it is again.

Let us say that we have 3 lists:

```
list1 = [1, 2]
list2 = [2, 3]
list3 = [1]
```

Let us say I want to find the 3 permutations of these list, which when added together, it results in the smallest number possible. So here, the permutations that we want would be:

1,2,1

2,2,1

1,3,1

Because the sum of the numbers on each permutation creates the smallest numbers possible.

2,3,1

Will not be a part of the solution since the sum is larger than the other three, thus, not a part of the three smallest.

Of course, using itertools and list all the permutations, and add the numbers on each permutation would be the most obvious solution, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient algorithm for this? Considering It should be able to take 1000 lists.

NOTE: If the number of list is N, then i would need to find N permutations. Thus, if there are 3 lists, I find the 3 smallest permutations.

PRECONDITIONS:

-A part of the precondition is that all of these lists are sorted.

-The number of elements on all list is 2N-1, to deal with the case where only one list have more than 1 element.

-All of the lists are sorted from smallest.

Comment: Still not sure what you're asking. What do you mean by _"the sum of the numbers on each permutation creates the smallest numbers possible"_?

Comment: Well yeah, that is the smallest sum, it gets more difficult on the second smallest sum. Considering if two lists have two of the same elements, we would have 4 extra permutations.

Comment: If you only need the smallest permutation, then you could use `perm = min(list1) + min(list2) + min(list3)`. But something in your question makes me think that you need more than just the smallest one, and I'm not sure why

Comment: Off the top of my head, this is not a permutation but a Cartesian product. You can use `itertools.product` for this, then add each output to check if it's the smallest among all permutations. `itertools` is efficient enough. I think one small tweak needs a bit of math: if all lists are sorted from lowest to highest, the smallest sum of N lists is the sum of all 0th elements.

Comment: MANA624, yes, i need to find more than just one. I need to find 3 smallest in this case

Comment: The Laughing Man, I used that, it is rather inefficient for large numbers though. I was thinking of next lexicographical permutation.

Comment: Padraic, I specifically said itertools was out of the question. I used that it takes forever to take an input of 1000 lists

Comment: I don't get it. Why does 2+2+1=5 create the smallest number possible? Only 1+2+1=4 does that.

Comment: @timgeb Because it's the next smallest. He said it above, if there are N lists, he needs to find the N lowest sums of Cartesian products.

Comment: @TheLaughingMan got it

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  You don't seem to understand. As stated before, with 1000 lists, I would need 1000 permutations.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the first three of `itertools.product` will use the first three items from the last list respectively, and be identical otherwise. These 3 products do not necessarily have the smalles sums of all products.

Comment: I just ran `itertools.product` against 1000 lists of 100 elements each with each element a random integer from 1 to 10 million. I got the 1000 smallest sums in a little under 2 seconds, which means I can get the products that caused those in a little over that. Unless my laptop is effing me up, you shouldn't have taken forever.

Comment: @TheLaughingMan I will try this. But one more thing, what do we use to put all that 1000 list into the input of the itertools.product?

Comment: Just input it as a list of lists. Say you have 1000 lists, just append them all into a variable like `x = []` by going `x.append(etc)` then go `itertools.product(x)`.

Comment: @TheLaughingMan  Are you sure? I already tried using a list of 3 lists. Doesn't come out as we want it. Maybe try printing each element produced by the itertools?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Hmm. consider `product(*sorted([[1,3,5],[2,5,8],[10,20,30]]))`, the first three are `(1, 2, 10)`, `(1, 2, 20)`, `(1, 2, 30)`. Those are clearly not the three smallest with regard to their sum.

Comment: Testing further. I think I might have answered a bit prematurely.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, yes, I realised after.

Comment: @TheLaughingMan: You screwed up somewhere. That `itertools.product` call would have given you `100**1000` possibilities to search through. Even `2**128` is considered too many possibilities for organizations like the NSA to search through.

Comment: I learned the necessary technique many years ago in a different language from http://perl.plover.com/Stream/stream.html.  Combining that with queues for efficiency is something I learned while doing Project Euler problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the lists are sorted, the smallest element in each list is the first one, the sum of which gives us the "minimal sum permutation". Picking any element except from the first one is going to increase the sum value.

We start off by calculating the difference between element *i* and the first one for each list. For example, for the lists `[1, 3, 4, 8]` and `[3, 9, 12, 15]`, these differences would be `[2, 3, 7]` and `[6, 9, 12]` respectively. We keep them separate in `cost_lists`, because they will be needed later on. But in `cost_global`, we pool them all together and by sorting them in ascending order, we find a solution where for all lists but one we choose the minimal value. To keep track which element from which list will give us the next minimum sum, we group the difference values with both the index of the list it comes from and which element in that list it is.

However, this is not a complete approach. It is possible, for example, that taking the next value from two lists incurs a smaller cost than taking the next value from one list. So, we have to search for the product of the combinations for k = 2, 3, ..., N. Doing that normally would result to N**N complexity, but we can take some really good shortcuts.

From the partial solution above, we have a list of the minimal costs in order. Since we want only the first N minimal sums, we check what the cost value of the Nth permutation is (threshold). So, when we search for a group of two next values, we can safely ignore their sum if it exceeds our current threshold. And since the difference values within lists are in ascending order, once we cross the threshold, we can instantly exit the loop. Similarly, if we haven't found any new combinations within the threshold for k = 2, it is pointless to look for k > 2. Considering that most likely the smallest sum costs will be the result of a single nonminimal value, or a few small ones (unless most lists have massive differences between sequential values), we are bound to exit these loops rather quickly. The code I came up to achieve this is fairly ugly, but it effectively does the same as

```
for k in xrange(2, len(lists)):
    for comb in itertools.combinations(cost_lists, k):
        for group in itertools.product(*comb):
            if sum(g[0] for g in group) <= threshold:
                cost_global.append(group)
```

except that we exit the loops as soon as we guarantee not to find any results, lest we pointlessly shift through an innumerable number of combinations/products which are over the threshold.

```
def filter_cost(cost_lists, threshold):
    cost = [[i for i in ilist if i[0] <= threshold] for ilist in cost_lists]
    # the algorithm requires that we remove any lists that have become empty
    return [ilist for ilist in cost if ilist]    

def _combi(cost_lists, k, start, depth, subtotal, threshold):
    if depth == k:
        for i in xrange(start, len(cost_lists)):
            for value in cost_lists[i]:
                if value[0] + subtotal > threshold:
                    break
                yield (value,)
    else:
        for i in xrange(start, len(cost_lists)):
            for value in cost_lists[i]:
                if value[0] + subtotal > threshold:
                    break
                for c in _combi(cost_lists, k, i+1, depth+1,
                                value[0]+subtotal, threshold):
                    yield (value,) + c

def combinations_product(cost_lists, k, threshold):
    for i in xrange(len(cost_lists)-k+1):
        for value in cost_lists[i]:
            if value[0] > threshold:
                break
            for comb in _combi(cost_lists, k, i+1, 2, value[0], threshold):
                temp = (value,) + comb
                cost, ilists, ith_items = zip(*temp)
                yield sum(cost), ilists, ith_items

def find_smallest_sum_permutations(lists):
    minima = [min(x) for x in lists]

    cost_local = []
    cost_global = []
    for i, ilist in enumerate(lists):
        if len(ilist) > 1:
            first = ilist[0]
            diff = [(num-first, i, j) for j, num in enumerate(ilist[1:], 1)]
            cost_local.append(diff)
            cost_global.extend(diff)
    cost_global.sort()

    threshold_index = len(lists) - 2
    cost_threshold = cost_global[threshold_index][0]
    cost_local = filter_cost(cost_local, cost_threshold)
    for k in xrange(2, len(lists)):
        group_combinations = tuple(combinations_product(cost_local, k,
                                                        cost_threshold))
        if group_combinations:
            cost_global.extend(group_combinations)
            cost_global.sort()
            cost_threshold = cost_global[threshold_index][0]
            cost_local = filter_cost(cost_local, cost_threshold)
        else:
            break

    permutations = [minima]
    for k in xrange(N-1):
        _, ilist, ith_item = cost_global[k]
        if type(ilist) == int:
            permutation = [minima[i]
                           if i != ilist else lists[ilist][ith_item]
                           for i in xrange(N)]
        else:
            # multiple nonminimal values combination
            mapping = dict(zip(ilist, ith_item))
            permutation = [minima[i]
                           if i not in mapping else lists[i][mapping[i]]
                           for i in xrange(N)]
        permutations.append(permutation)
    return permutations
```

**Examples**

Example in the question.

```
>>> lists = [
    [1, 2],
    [2, 3],
    [1],
]
>>> for p in find_smallest_sum_permutations(lists):
...     print p, sum(p)

[1, 2, 1] 4
[2, 2, 1] 5
[1, 3, 1] 5
```

Example I had generated with random lists.

```
>>> import random
>>> N = 5
>>> random.seed(1024)
>>> lists = [sorted(random.sample(range(10*N), 2*N-1)) for _ in xrange(N)]
>>> for p in find_smallest_sum_permutations(lists):
...     print p, sum(p)

[4, 4, 1, 6, 0] 15
[4, 6, 1, 6, 0] 17
[4, 4, 3, 6, 0] 17
[4, 4, 1, 6, 4] 19
[4, 6, 3, 6, 0] 19
```

Example by user2357112 which had caught a glaring error in my previous iteration.

```
>>> lists = [
    [1, 2, 30, 40],
    [1, 2, 30, 40],
    [10, 20, 30, 40],
    [10, 20, 30, 40],
]
>>> for p in find_smallest_sum_permutations(lists):
...     print p, sum(p)

[1, 1, 10, 10] 22
[2, 1, 10, 10] 23
[1, 2, 10, 10] 23
[2, 2, 10, 10] 24
```

Comment: Any feedback for that downvote? My solution, to the best of my knowledge, works according to the constraints of the OP and I tried to explain it as well as possible.

Comment: [I'm downvoting because this answer never considers the possibility of taking nonminimal elements from more than one input.](http://ideone.com/SHEePY)

Comment: For example, the fifth output in the case you tried should have been `[4, 6, 3, 6, 0]`, for a total of 19 instead of 20.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for catching the error in my previous approach. I'd like to believe this is correct this time.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to only generate the combinations that might possibly be needed, and store them in a heap.  Each one that you pull out is the smallest one you have not yet seen.  And the fact that THAT combination has been pulled out tells you that there are new ones which might also be small.

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html for how to use a heap.  We also need code for generating combinations.  And with that, here is working code for getting the first `n` combinations for any list of lists:

```
import heapq

# Helper class for storing combinations.
class ListSelector:
    def __init__(self, lists, indexes):
        self.lists = lists
        self.indexes = indexes

    def value(self):
        answer = 0
        for i in range(0, len(self.lists)):
            answer = answer + self.lists[i][self.indexes[i]]
        return answer

    def values(self):
       return [self.lists[i][self.indexes[i]] for i in range(0, len(self.lists))]

    # These are the next combinations.  We are willing to increment any
    # leading 0, or the first non-zero value.  This will provide one and
    # only one path to each possible combination.
    def next_selectors(self):
        lists = self.lists
        indexes = self.indexes
        selectors = []
        for i in range(0, len(lists)):
            if len(lists[i]) <= indexes[i] + 1:
                if 0 == indexes[i]:
                    continue
                else:
                    break
            new_indexes = [
                indexes[j] + (0 if j != i else 1)
                    for j in range(0, len(lists))]
            selectors.append(ListSelector(lists, new_indexes))
            if 0 < indexes[i]:
                break
        return selectors


# This will just return an iterator over all combinations, from smallest
# to largest.  It does NOT generate them until needed.    
def combinations(lists):
    sel = ListSelector(lists, [0 for _ in range(len(lists))])
    upcoming = [(sel.value(), sel)]
    while len(upcoming):
        value, sel = heapq.heappop(upcoming)
        yield sel
        for next_sel in sel.next_selectors():
            heapq.heappush(upcoming, (next_sel.value(), next_sel))


# This just gets the first n of them.  (It will return less if less.)
def smallest_n_combinations(n, lists):
    i = 0
    for sel in combinations(lists):
        yield sel
        i = i + 1
        if i == n:
            break

# Example usage
lists = [
    [1, 2, 5],
    [2, 3, 4],
    [1]]

for sel in smallest_n_combinations(3, lists):
    print(sel.value(), sel.values(), sel.indexes)
```

(This could be made more efficient for a long list of lists with tricks like caching the value inside of ListSelector and calculating it incrementally for new ones.)

Comment: @Reti43 I did not call `sel.value()` properly so it wasn't coming in order.  Sorry.  Try the fixed version.

Comment: Yeah, bad cut and paste.  Fixed.