# Need to Match sets of parts to Minimize Value

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, sorting, mathematical-optimization

Real World Problem:

I have multiple buckets of different parts (Part A, Part B, Part C). Each part has an x and y value ((x_a, y_a), (x_b, y_b), (x_c, y_c))representing a vector. There are the same number of each part (say 4 of each). Sets containing 1 of each part (A, B, C) must be put together such that the root sum square of the sums of the x and y values of the parts is as low as possible sqrt(sum(x)^2 + sum(y)^2)), i.e the length of the resultant vector after the components from each part are added together. All parts should be used, but no part can be used more than once.

The ideal solution has the lowest length resultant vector across all sets of parts (i.e.using four of each part, you get 4 unique sets of parts with a low resultant, not one perfect one and the rest whatever else is left). Since the length of the resultant is a scaler, it would be the value closest to zero desired. There is also a maximum resultant that cannot be exceeded

In Code:

I am using pandas to create DataFrames from each .csv file, then find every combination of parts and the resultant/root sum square attribute for each combination, see below:

```
i=1

for index, row in A.iterrows():
    #Get a Row of Data in one DataFrame
    SN_A = row['Serial Number']
    X_A = row['X']
    Y_A = row['Y']
    for index, row in B.iterrows():
        #Get Row of Data in second DataFrame
        SN_B = row['Serial Number']
        X_B = row['X']
        Y_B = row['Y']
        for index, row in C.iterrows():
            #Get Row of Data in Third DataFrame
            SN_C = row['Serial Number']
            X_C = row['X']
            Y_C = row['Y']
            
            #After all data taken from DataFrame for one row, Combine and calculate Resultant 
            #Data and store in new DataFrame. Repeat until all combinations found   
            X_tot = X_A + X_B + X_C
            Y_tot = Y_A + Y_B + Y_C
            Res = math.sqrt((X_tot**2)+(Y_tot**2))
            Combo.loc[i] = [SN_A, SN_B, SN_C, X_tot, Y_tot, Res]
            i=i+1

#Sort DataFrame to find best sets of parts

#Combo.sort_values(by=['Resultant'], inplace=True)
```

From here though, I'm not sure how to get the best group of sets.

You could take the single best performing set, remove those parts from the population, calculate again, and repeat until are parts are in a set, but this typically leaves the last set with poor performance (as it is essentially just the leftovers).

The single best performing set is not necessarily a part of the group of sets with the best combined performance.

I'm not sure if finding every possible combination is correct, as while the amount of unique combinations of parts is:

> (How much of each part)**(number of types of part),

the number of unique sets (meaning the number of ways all parts can be used) is different.

Comment: 1. Are there any negative x(or y) values?
2. The last paragraph seems to be contradictory to the first paragraph about "the best performing set". You should provide a clear definition for that.

Comment: It is because you can get top-N best performing sets after sorting the data frame.

Comment: I think I have addressed your questions to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

I have adopted [a stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36341895) to reflect your requirement as follows:

### Algorithm

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import heapq

class PartSelector:
    def __init__(self, buckets, part_indices):
        self.buckets = buckets
        self.part_indices = part_indices

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.cost() < other.cost()
    
    def cost(self):
        total_X = 0
        total_Y = 0
        for i in range(0, len(self.buckets)):
            total_X += self.buckets[i][self.part_indices[i]][0]
            total_Y += self.buckets[i][self.part_indices[i]][1]
        return np.sqrt(total_X ** 2 + total_Y ** 2)

    def get_actual_parts(self):
        return [self.buckets[i][self.part_indices[i]] for i in range(0, len(self.buckets))]
    
    def get_next_combination(self):
        buckets = self.buckets
        indexes = self.part_indices
        selectors = []
        for i in range(0, len(buckets)):
            if len(buckets[i]) <= indexes[i] + 1:
                if 0 == indexes[i]:
                    continue
                else:
                    break
            new_indexes = [
                indexes[j] + (0 if j != i else 1)
                    for j in range(0, len(buckets))]
            selectors.append(PartSelector(buckets, new_indexes))
            if 0 < indexes[i]:
                break
        return selectors


# This returns an iterator over all combinations from smallest to largest.    
def get_lazy_combinations(buckets):
    a_part_selector = PartSelector(buckets, [0 for _ in range(len(buckets))])
    candidate_combination = [(a_part_selector.cost(), a_part_selector)]
    while len(candidate_combination):
        _, a_part_selector = heapq.heappop(candidate_combination)
        yield a_part_selector
        for next_part_selector in a_part_selector.get_next_combination():
            heapq.heappush(candidate_combination, (next_part_selector.cost(), next_part_selector))


# This gets the top n parts of the smallest cost
def get_top_N_smallest_combinations(buckets, n=None):
    if None is n:
        for sel in get_lazy_combinations(buckets):
            yield sel
    else:
        i = 0
        for sel in get_lazy_combinations(buckets):
            yield sel
            i = i + 1
            if i == n:
                break

def get_optimal_indices(indices, buckets):
    n_buckets = len(buckets)
    optimal_indices = []
    optimal_parts = []
    for i in range(1, n_buckets):
        cur_indices = [(c + i) % n_buckets for c in indices]
        optimal_indices.append(cur_indices)
        cur_parts = [buckets[i][cur_indices[i]] for i in range(0, len(buckets))]
        optimal_parts.append(cur_parts)
    return optimal_parts, optimal_indices

def cost(buckets, part_indices):
    total_X = 0
    total_Y = 0
    for i in range(0, len(buckets)):
        total_X += buckets[i][part_indices[i]][0]
        total_Y += buckets[i][part_indices[i]][1]
    return np.sqrt(total_X ** 2 + total_Y ** 2)
    
def find_the_optimal_sets(all_sets, buckets):
    results = []
    visited = set()
    for initial_cost, actual_parts, indices in all_sets:
        if tuple(indices) in visited:
            continue
        optimal_parts, optimal_indices = get_optimal_indices(indices, buckets)
        cur_parts = [actual_parts] + optimal_parts
        cur_indices = [indices] + optimal_indices
        for cur_indice in cur_indices:
            visited.add(tuple(cur_indice))
        costs = []
        for a_set in cur_indices:
            costs.append(cost(buckets, a_set))
        average_cost = np.mean(costs)
        results.append((initial_cost, average_cost, cur_indices, cur_parts))
    df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=["Initial cost", "Average cost", "Part indices", "Actual parts"])
    df.sort_values(by=["Average cost", "Initial cost"], ascending=[True, True], inplace=True)
    return df
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    buckets = [
        [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)], # buckets A
        [(5, 6), (6, 7), (7, 8), (8, 9)], # buckets B
        [(9, 10), (10, 11), (11, 12), (12, 13)], # buckets C
        [(13, 14), (14, 15), (15, 16), (16, 17)] # buckets D
        ]
    
    all_sets = []
    for sel in get_top_N_smallest_combinations(buckets):
        all_sets.append([sel.cost(), sel.get_actual_parts(), sel.part_indices])
    df = find_the_optimal_sets(all_sets, buckets)
    print(df.head(10))
```

### Result

```
    Initial cost  Average cost                                              Part indices                                                                                                                                             Actual parts
58     50.990195     50.990195  [[2, 0, 1, 3], [3, 1, 2, 0], [0, 2, 3, 1], [1, 3, 0, 2]]  [[(3, 4), (5, 6), (10, 11), (16, 17)], [(4, 5), (6, 7), (11, 12), (13, 14)], [(1, 2), (7, 8), (12, 13), (14, 15)], [(2, 3), (8, 9), (9, 10), (15, 16)]]
59     50.990195     50.990195  [[2, 1, 0, 3], [3, 2, 1, 0], [0, 3, 2, 1], [1, 0, 3, 2]]  [[(3, 4), (6, 7), (9, 10), (16, 17)], [(4, 5), (7, 8), (10, 11), (13, 14)], [(1, 2), (8, 9), (11, 12), (14, 15)], [(2, 3), (5, 6), (12, 13), (15, 16)]]
60     50.990195     50.990195  [[0, 2, 1, 3], [1, 3, 2, 0], [2, 0, 3, 1], [3, 1, 0, 2]]  [[(1, 2), (7, 8), (10, 11), (16, 17)], [(2, 3), (8, 9), (11, 12), (13, 14)], [(3, 4), (5, 6), (12, 13), (14, 15)], [(4, 5), (6, 7), (9, 10), (15, 16)]]
61     50.990195     50.990195  [[2, 1, 3, 0], [3, 2, 0, 1], [0, 3, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2, 3]]  [[(3, 4), (6, 7), (12, 13), (13, 14)], [(4, 5), (7, 8), (9, 10), (14, 15)], [(1, 2), (8, 9), (10, 11), (15, 16)], [(2, 3), (5, 6), (11, 12), (16, 17)]]
62     50.990195     50.990195  [[2, 3, 0, 1], [3, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 0]]  [[(3, 4), (8, 9), (9, 10), (14, 15)], [(4, 5), (5, 6), (10, 11), (15, 16)], [(1, 2), (6, 7), (11, 12), (16, 17)], [(2, 3), (7, 8), (12, 13), (13, 14)]]
63     50.990195     50.990195  [[1, 2, 0, 3], [2, 3, 1, 0], [3, 0, 2, 1], [0, 1, 3, 2]]  [[(2, 3), (7, 8), (9, 10), (16, 17)], [(3, 4), (8, 9), (10, 11), (13, 14)], [(4, 5), (5, 6), (11, 12), (14, 15)], [(1, 2), (6, 7), (12, 13), (15, 16)]]
46     49.578221     50.990367  [[1, 0, 1, 3], [2, 1, 2, 0], [3, 2, 3, 1], [0, 3, 0, 2]]  [[(2, 3), (5, 6), (10, 11), (16, 17)], [(3, 4), (6, 7), (11, 12), (13, 14)], [(4, 5), (7, 8), (12, 13), (14, 15)], [(1, 2), (8, 9), (9, 10), (15, 16)]]
47     49.578221     50.990367  [[0, 1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 2, 0], [2, 3, 3, 1], [3, 0, 0, 2]]  [[(1, 2), (6, 7), (10, 11), (16, 17)], [(2, 3), (7, 8), (11, 12), (13, 14)], [(3, 4), (8, 9), (12, 13), (14, 15)], [(4, 5), (5, 6), (9, 10), (15, 16)]]
48     49.578221     50.990367  [[3, 0, 2, 0], [0, 1, 3, 1], [1, 2, 0, 2], [2, 3, 1, 3]]  [[(4, 5), (5, 6), (11, 12), (13, 14)], [(1, 2), (6, 7), (12, 13), (14, 15)], [(2, 3), (7, 8), (9, 10), (15, 16)], [(3, 4), (8, 9), (10, 11), (16, 17)]]
49     49.578221     50.990367  [[0, 3, 1, 1], [1, 0, 2, 2], [2, 1, 3, 3], [3, 2, 0, 0]]  [[(1, 2), (8, 9), (10, 11), (14, 15)], [(2, 3), (5, 6), (11, 12), (15, 16)], [(3, 4), (6, 7), (12, 13), (16, 17)], [(4, 5), (7, 8), (9, 10), (13, 14)]]
```

**Note:**

1. You can specify the number of combinations to be selected among the initial sets.
2. The initial sets are sorted by the cost. We can select an initial set and the next sets (sets in a group) can be calculated by adding [1..number of buckets).
3. We do not calculate the cost of a set that is a member of the visited set.

Comment: 1. "There" is in the real world. I am attempting to create a script to solve a problem  in the real world
2. The "bucket" has some quantity of parts. For example, the bucket for part A in this example had 4 "A" parts, A1, A2, A3, A4. A set would contain one part of each type/one from each bucket, so 1 A part, 1 B part, 1 C part. A complete group of sets is the result of using all of the parts in each "bucket" to create multiple "sets" (for example, one solution would be the group of sets "A1+B1+C1", "A2+B2+C2" , "A3+B3+C3", "A4+B4+C4")

Comment: 3. Yes. the X and Y values represent each part's deviation from nominal. The parts need to be combined to minimize the deviation of each set. The components of the deviation (the x and y values) stack linearly, but the desired result the magnitude of the deviation of the part after being matched together, which is the root sum square of the components

4. Tring to say the total number of individual part combinations. in this example, there are 4x of three types of parts, becomes 4**3 = 4*4*4 = 64 part individual part combinations.

Comment: @PaulHubner So is your original code working correctly as you explained? What is your desired goal, e.g., improving performance or correcting logic..

Comment: @PaulHubner In addition, if I understood you correctly, you do not need to remove the single best performing set from the population to find alternatives because your code creates all the possible combinations. For the 4-parts-in-each-bucket example, your code creates 64 combinations.

Comment: @PaulHubner I have added another algorithm. Please accept my answer if it solved your question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just finding all of the individual sets, which I have been able to do . I still need a way to determine the best performing group of sets that uses all of the parts.

Comment: For example, starting with the best performing set (index [0,0,0,0]) to get the next set for the group we can pick the next best performing set that does not use any of the parts used already. That set is indexed [1,1,1,1]. Repeating gives the group of sets [0,0,0,0],  [1,1,1,1],  [2,2,2,2],  [3,3,3,3]. The average of these four sets is 50.991. 

Instead first using the set indexed  [0,0,0,3] yields the sets indexed  [1,1,1,0],  [2,2,2,1],  [3,3,3,2] to complete the group. This set has an average of 50.989. The goal is to find the group with the lowest performance (the average of the 4 sets)

Comment: @PaulHubner I have updated the answer according to your comment. It would have been much clearer if you had provided desired outputs initially. Yet, I am unsure whether the algorithm solves your question.